# Can I include a module method in a class?

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
module X
  class << self
    def x() %s(hi5) end
  end

  def y() rand(65..122).chr end
end

class Object
  include X

  # Here I want class Object to have x() from the X module.
end

puts y # => A random character from ('A'..'z')
# puts x
```

I want to call `x` in the same way I am calling `y`. Can I do that?

Comment: Yeah, for most of the application I write, if the method can be written in one line, I don't misuse the capability of adding new lines - it makes the code lengthy. I am not sure if that's a good practice though. I do it all the time! That doesn't raise any kind of waning, or doesn't do any harm. It even doesn't need semicolon! So it's basically a one line short code!

Comment: The one-line definition style is against nearly every Ruby coding style guide, so you'll want to avoid it. It tends to make your code far harder to read. Tools like [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop) will give you a citation for using it.

Comment: Rubocop is pretty strict. But where can I get that using `def(*arg) end` in a line is a bad practice? The Rubocop team could make that up. I want a site that documents it properly.

I want a fast code with a fast algorithm with the warning flag on while running. If Ruby doesn't warn, I shouldn't care that much.

I know it's a bad practice to use semicolons. But I didn't use one. It runs perfectly.

Apart from Rubocop can you give me a link that says defining a method in one line is a bad practice?

Comment: It's a matter of style and convention, and these evolve out of traditions. You can indent your Ruby code with nine spaces, or thirty, or six hundred, nobody can stop you, but the overwhelming convention is two. The same goes for single-line definitions: Traditionally these have been avoided because they go against the principle of having readable, understandable at-a-glance Ruby code. There's no specific documentation for each best-practice, but Rubocop does try and communicate the community's thinkings on any particular angle.

Comment: The "When in Rome" principle applies here. Ruby has conventions and if you don't follow them your code will work, but your code will seem very strange to someone familiar with Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although one would not likely see this in practice, you could do that as follows.

```
module X
  def self.x
    :hi5
  end

  def self.v(str)
    str.capitalize
  end

  def self.z(str)
    yield(str)
  end

  def y
    :ho
  end
end
```

```
X.x
  #=> :hi5
X.v("cat")
  #=> "Cat"
X.z("cat") { |s| s.upcase }
  #=> "CAT"
```

```
class Object
  include X
  X.methods(false).each do |m|
    define_method(m) { |*args, &block|
      X.method(m).call(*args, &block) }
  end
end
  #=> [:v, :x, :z]

Object.instance_methods && [:x, :v, :z, :y]
  #=> [:x, :v, :z, :y]
```

```
o = Object.new

o.x
  #=> :hi5
o.v("cat")
  #=> "Cat"
o.z("cat") { |s| s.upcase }
  #=> "CAT"
o.y
  #=> :ho
```

This also works.

```
x #=> :hi5
v("cat")
  #=> "Cat"
z("cat") { |s| s.upcase }
  #=> "CAT"
y #=> "m"
```

Why? Because `x` is the same as `self.x` (`self #=> main`) and

```
self.is_a? Object
  #=> true
```

Note

```
module X
  def self.m
    #...
  end
end
```

is shorthand for

```
module X
  class << self
    def m
      #...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The real answer. You should have answered first here!

Comment: `X.z("cat") { |s| s.upcase }`
Why did you give X.z() a block?  I don't get it. Is that really necessary?

Comment: That was an artefact that I've now removed.

Comment: I don't mind downvotes but I ask the culprit to step out of the shadows and justify it. Personally, I never downvote an answer without providing an explanation in a comment. I believe the OP deserves an answer and often can learn something from it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The alternative here may be automatic delegation instead of constructing a bridge method. Consider applying [Forwardable](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html).

Comment: @tadman, that's an interesting idea. I've heard of that module but little more. Would you be interested in exploring it as an edit to your answer or a separate answer?

Comment: It'll take some fussing to get right in this case, so if you want to try by all means.

Comment: Speaking of downvotes, I have seen that many downvoted the question just because monkey patching Object class is a bad idea. Yes, I am aware of that. It's not a professional code I am writing, this is a mere scratchpad where I want to do what I think I will do. I got three answers where yours is what I think is correct. Yes, it's a bad practice, but as @tadman suggests `puts z # Error, as this can't be included`, it's actually not impossible. I don't mind the downvotes either. If someone can't answer, they tend to downvote! That's pretty weird on stackoverflow.

Comment: @SouravGoswami You'll note that it's still "impossible" to do with a simple `include`. What Cary's done here is a lot more than that. One thing to remember when asking questions here is we're often sensitive to [XY Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), and want to steer towards "Why are you doing this? It seems like a bad plan. If you can better explain your ultimate objective we can give you a better way". Doing strange things with Ruby just because you can does rub people the wrong way, but don't get too worried. Down-votes are just opinions.

Comment: In my experience I've learned a lot by answering questions that ask if crazy things are possible.

Answer (score 2):

If you define `x` the same way you define `y`, then yes. The `class << self` part makes `x` a module method only, it can't be added with `include`. So to fix:

```
module X
  def x
    %s(hi5)
  end

  def y
    rand(65..122).chr
  end

  def self.z
    :nope
  end
end

class Object
  include X
end

puts x
puts y
puts z # Error, as this can't be included
```

Here `z` has been added using the `self.z` declaration method that's a lot less fuss than `class << self` but has the same effect.

As a note, Ruby methods without arguments have their brackets omitted. You should also separate the method definition and body by a newline.

Comment: I have a module that has this kind of module method. I want to use that with Object! That's the idea... I can't easily that line from every module, that should break the program if any one wants to run it by downloading the gem.

Comment: When methods are declared that way they're walled off from being included on purpose. You generally call them directly, like `X.z` in this case, but remember you can always make an alias for them if necessary. `def y; X.y; end` for example. Adding things to `Object` directly is usually bad form, so avoid cluttering up that namespace if you can.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to want to do is to include new instance methods while extending your class with new class methods. The following is based on the PICK AXE book:

```
module X
  module ClassMethods
    def x()
      puts "In class"
    end
  end

  def y()
    puts "In instance"
  end

  def self.included(host_class)
    host_class.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end

class Object
  include X
end
```

And now

```
# Test the instance method
Object.new.y  # Prints "In instance"

# Test the class method
Object.x   # Prints "In class"
```

Comment: Exactly this is the answer I wanted.
Instead of `extend`, I used `include`.
I omitted `puts` inside the methods.
Instead of `Object.new.x`, I wrote `puts x`.
This is what my desirous result is.
Thank you very much!

Comment: That was the idea. To allow you to bridge the gap to what you wanted to do.

Comment: The question is whether module methods can be used as instance methods in a class, not whether a module's instance methods can be used as class methods.

Comment: I too am retired with Ruby as my main hobby. I dabbled with various languages during my working years but never the low-level stuff.